# How to save/serialize information in executable .jar java files

Tags: java, serialization, jvm, save, saving-data

I recently made a simple Gui Library program, which can make new books and store them on shelves. When I ran the application from eclipse, it serialized the files and When I reopened the application, I was able to load old information off of it.

However, when I converted it into an .app and ran it, it functioned normally, but I was unable to save (serialize) data, and consequently not able to retrieve data when I opened it up again.

I tried searching my computer for that .ser file, but it seemed to not have been created.

I assume this has something to do with the JVM, but I'm not so familiar with the ins and outs of the JVM. It also may not. Do you know why my program wouldn't serialize properly and how I could fix it

Thanks
M.R.

Comment: Are you running it on a Mac? What's the location you're storing/reading the files from?

Comment: yes, I'm running it from a mac. I have the .app stored in /Users/MosheRosensweig/Documents/Coding_Programming\ Stuff/Making_Apps/Apps

Comment: It’s not unusual that the archive containing the running application can’t be written to. How many (native) applications store their data inside their executable? The other problem seems to be your program not reporting exceptions which occurred while writing…